# What is the difference between [MUI]'s Link and [react-router-dom]'s Link in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The `<Link>` tag of **Material UI** is compiled to `<a>` tag.
And the Link of `react-router-dom` is compiled to `<a>` tag.

But the `<Link>` of MUI makes re-rendering.
What is the main difference between two `<a>` tags?
Thanks for your kind attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router's `<Link>` component does not cause a page refresh when it's clicked (React Router handles client-side navigation), but regular `<a>` elements and those from MUI will because they are not directly related to the router.

You can use the `component` property of MUI's link to make it render using React Router's `<Link>`.

```
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import { Link as ReactRouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link component={ReactRouterLink} to="/path">
    Link Text
</Link>
```